# The song in Naruto ep. 13 when Haku uses Crystal Ice Mirrors

Tags: naruto, music

There's a song in *Naruto* episode 13, around 17:11 when Haku uses Crystal Ice Mirrors. It's really somber.

I have been searching for this forever.

What is the title and the OST of the song?

Answer (score 2):

The song you are looking for is [Haku's theme](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fAYLF6E2ivQ)

Haku's theme never made it to an OST, and is therefor an unreleased soundtrack. And judging by how long ago it has been used, I am assuming it will not be released as one either.